# Windows 7 loses network drive mappings on log-off

Tags: windows-7, mapped-drive

Each time I log off I lose some drive mappings that I set up. I do not have the "Reconnect at Logon" box checked when mapping these drives. Is there some way to prevent these drives from being disconnected each time I log off?

**Update:** The reason I had "Reconnect at Logon" unchecked is because on WinXP this used to in fact *disconnect* my network drives everything I logged on. It seems that having this box checked in Win7 doesn't seem to help and when I log off and on the drive is now mapped to a different location than the one I selected.

**Update2:** I tried using the suggested command

```
net use L: \\server\etc /user:Anakin Jedi /persistent:yet
```

but the drive still got remapped to the default location (not the one I specified). Is is possible that there is some sort of override happening for this specific drive on a startup script (this is a work machine)?

**Update3:** Seems that some hidden startup script overrides the specific network drive I was mapping, so each time I logged off I lost the specific mapping that I set up - now that  I changed the drive letter, I am able to successfully keep the mapping.

Comment: `I do not have the "Reconnect at Logon" box checked when mapping these drives.` - Well there you have it. If you want the drive mappings to persist across a logoff and/or reboot then check this box.

Comment: The answer is evident in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the box.

If you are connecting via a log in script, make sure it also uses the `/persistent:yes` switch. For example:

```
net use z: \\server\share /user:canadian luke /persistent:yes
```

(Yes, using `luke` as a password in the example) This is the intended behaviour. Check the box, and tell Windows you want it.

If this does not work, then it is likely a script is clearing that drive mapping. Many companies do this to ensure that certain network locations are always mapped to the same location. An example in a script may simply be `net use x: /delete` (for a single drive mapping), or the evil `net use * /delete` to remove *all* mappings.

If this is the case, you can either talk to your SysAdmin about adding your custom mappings, or create a script on your desktop that you can run after logging in. I would normally suggest putting it in the Startup folder, but sometimes, scripts run in the wrong order and we won't know why.

Comment: I tried using the above command, and the network drive was mapped. However, once I logged off I lost the connection and it went back to the default.

Comment: Then you have a script running that's disconnecting drives on you. Every system that I use the Persistent switch on, or check the box, keeps the drive mappings *unless a script is clearing all mappings beforehand*.

Comment: That's what I feared - thankfully it only overwrites a specific drive and not all of them :)